# Store environment-specific OSGI Configurations for CQ

Tags: configuration, osgi, aem, day-cq

I'd like to store the Felix configurations we've made in SVN and have them applied to CQ in the packages produced by an automated build.  To do this I have been following the instructions found in **[this CQ5 OSGI Configuration Document](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_osgi.html#OSGi%20Configuration%20in%20the%20Repository)** to create sling:OsgiConfig configuration nodes that get checked into SVN.

How can I store **environment-specific** configurations?  For example, I want a different logging configuration for the DEV environment than the PROD environment will use.  I would like to store the config for ***both*** environments in SVN ideally and have the environment pick which config to use somehow based on the environment.

How can I do that--or is there a different approach that I should be using for environment-specific configurations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have environment-specific configurations, you should use Run Modes in CQ5 - there is plenty of information here on how to achieve [**this_page**](http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5/CQ5SystemAdministration/RunModeDependentConfigAndInstall.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  After digging into your link and understanding run modes better, I found this link on defining run modes to also be useful: http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5/CQ5SystemAdministration/RunModeSetUp.html

Comment: Check out the [runmodes and configs for fun and profit](http://www.pro-vision.de/content/medialib/pro-vision/production/adaptto/2011/2011_lightning_runmodesandconfigsforfunandprofit-pdf/_jcr_content/renditions/rendition.file/2011_lightning_runmodes_and_configs_for_fun_and_profit.pdf) presentation by Mike Pfaff for a _lot_ more detail on runmodes and configuration